# Algorithm for determining similarity of objects

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I need some help coming up with an algorithm for the following scenario:

I have a function that takes in a list of a list of objects. These objects are of the form [type, value], where type is one of four options (lets just say, between a number between 0-3), and value can be arbitrary.

So the input might be something like:

{ { [0, 5], [1, 8] }, { [0,5], [3, 88] }, { [0,5], [1,25], [3,88] } }

What I need the algorithm to do is, create a list called commonList and uncommonList. commonList will contain just the type part of the pair, but only if every set in the list has the same value for that type. uncommonList will contain the type of every [type,value] pair that is not identicle/part of every set in the list.

So with the example input:

commonList = { 0 }
uncommonList = { 1, 3 }

commonList contains the value 0, because every set has a pair with type 0, and each pair has the same value.

uncommonList contains the value 1 because all 3 sets do not contain the same [1, value] pair. Same situation for the value 3.

I am having some difficult coming up with this algorithm. I will edit and post some of the code I have now, just need to generalize it a bit first

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Mostly coming up with a efficient algorithm to complete the task.

Comment: Just create a map key -> list of values. Then check for which keys the list of values contains only 1 value.

Comment: Problem with that is, for an item to make the commonList it has to be in EVERY set. So if one set has the value [2,5], and no other set has a pair with type 2, then we should place this in the uncommonList, not the commonList.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your problem, you want to find the set of pairs [key,value] common to all sets.

To reach efficiently that goal, what you can do is the following:

- Initialize the common set of pairs CoP with the content of the first set. Each element of CoP is the original pair plus one extra counting integer. In your example, `CoP <- { {[0, 5],0}, {[1, 8],0} }'
- For each set, do:

  - reset the associated integer of each pair in CoP.
  - for each pair:

    - if the pair exists in CoP, increment the associated counting integer.
  - scan all pairs in CoP:

    - remove every pair that has not been visited once, i.e. every pair with its associated integer equal to 0.
  - if CoP is empty, end here
- commonList is the set of all types of elements in CoP; uncommonList is the complement in the set of all possible types.

If you can guarantee that you have real sets of objects (not twice the same object in a set), you can go faster:

- Initialize the common set of pairs CoP with the content of the first set. Each element of CoP is the original pair plus one extra counting integer. In your example, `CoP <- { {[0, 5],0}, {[1, 8],0} }'
- For each set, do:

  - for each pair:

    - if the pair exists in CoP, increment the associated counting integer.
- Scan all pairs in CoP:

  - remove every pair that has not been visited once per set, i.e. every pair with its associated integer not equal to the number of sets of objects.
- commonList is the set of all types of elements in CoP; uncommonList is the complement in the set of all possible types.

You can generalize this easily with a distance between objects (same objects if their distance is below a certain value).